# SIGCONT Handler for terminal application

Tags: c++, posix, signal-handling

I'm writing a C++ application for POSIX environment with terminal-based User Interface. I'd like to make my application's UI be consistent between `Ctrl-Z` and `fg`(i.e: `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT`).

Here is a minimal example (without using longjmp. this code uses C and POSIX headers only, but entire application will be C++):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>

void PrintMessage() {
    printf("Press q to quit");
}

sig_atomic_t signalCheck;

void SigCONTHandler(int sig) {
    if(sig != SIGCONT) {
        return;
    }   
    printf("From Signal Handler\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    if(signalCheck != 0) {
        PrintMessage();
    }   
}

int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    signal(SIGCONT, SigCONTHandler);

    int ch = 0;
    while(true) {
        PrintMessage();
        signalCheck = 1;
        ch = getchar();
        signalCheck = 0;
        if(ch == 'q') {
            break;
        }   
        if(ch == EOF) {
            printf("I asked you to process q.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }   
    }   
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Usage(Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4, TERM=linux):

```
$ ./app
Press q to quit
Press q to quit
Press q to quit
Press q to quit
Press q to quit^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./app
$ fg
./app
From Signal Handler
Press q to quit
Press q to quitq
```

This code works as intended, but I feel this code is Bad. `signalCheck` variable keep own state to check whether the application need to print `PrintMessage()` or not. However, if a application become complex, I don't think I can print whole thing to `stdout` in `SigContHandler`. Moreover, it won't work without `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`, so I'm trying to make it with `longjmp` to restore state.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <unistd.h>

sigjmp_buf jumpBuffer;

void PrintMessage() {
    printf("Press q to quit");
}

void SigCONTHandler(int sig) {
    if(sig != SIGCONT) {
        return;
    }   
    printf("From Signal Handler\n");
    siglongjmp(jumpBuffer, 1); 
}

int main() {
    // setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    signal(SIGCONT, SigCONTHandler);

    int ch = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(sigsetjmp(jumpBuffer, 1) == 0) {
            PrintMessage();
            ch = getchar();
            if(ch == 'q') {
                break;
            }   
            if(ch == EOF) {
                printf("I asked you to process q.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code works, and I don't need to turn off stdout buffer, but this code also looks bad.

If I need to choose one of them, what I need to choose it? Is it portable from latest Linux to old Unix box?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. In any case, calling `printf` from a signal handler is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @vnp I didn't know that. It is okay to change it to `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)`? Can I use printf after longjmp?

Comment: Since `write` translates directly to a system call, it it kind of safe. In doubt, consult `man 7 signal-safety`.